# Calling C++ from JIT code (calling convention)

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit, jit

I'm programming a JIT compiler, that has to call c++ functions from the compiled asm code.

I'm working on Windows x64 only so far and implemented the calling convention from microsoft. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx)

It works, until it doesn't.

If the called function is simple and only calls functions that are simple (uses a C like subset), it seems to always work.
If the called function calls other functions, e.g. "std::cout", it works if it's compiled for Debug, but not for release.
If the called function calls some VULKAN functions, it doesn't work at all.

Example of the code the jit compiler generates:

```
sub  %10 r64(4),  imm8(48)
mov  %1 r64(0),  %6 r64(1)
mov  %2 r64(2),  m64[%1]
mov  %3 r32(1),  imm32(5)
mov  ST: m64 +40,  %2 r64(2)
call  m64 <call PrintInt()>
mov  %2 r64(2),  ST: m64 +40
mov  m32[%2] +16,  %4 r32(0)
mov  %5 r32(0),  imm32(-2)
add  %10 r64(4),  imm8(48)
ret
```

Object (dump into https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/ with x86-64):

```
48 83 EC 30 48 89 C8 48 8B 10 B9 05 00 00 00 48 89 54 24 28 FF 15 D6 FF FF FF 48 8B 54 24 28 89 42 10 B8 FE FF FF FF 48 83 C4 30 C3
```

The function called is as simple as (fails in release):

```
int PrintInt(int nr) {
std::cout << nr << std::endl;   // error
return nr;
}
```

The error is:
"Exception thrown at 0x000007FEE3693D39 (msvcp140.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000."

Any idea what I'm missing?

Edit the disassembly with my comments

```
sub rsp, 0x30               // subtract 48 bytes from stack pointer to get 6 slots of space
mov rax, rcx                // rcx is a pointer parameter
mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]    // load pointer from [rax]
mov ecx, 0x5                // imm 5 into ecx for function call
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+0x28], rdx   // save rdx for after function call on the stack
call QWORD PTR [..]         // function call
mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+0x28]   // get rdx back from stack
mov DWORD PTR [rdx+0x10], eax   // save result
mov eax, 0xfffffffe             // -2 in eax (return value)
add rsp, 0x30               // restore stack ptr (free)
ret
```

STACK:

```
.... start
[XXX] used to save rdx
[   ] unused
[ s ]
[ s ]
[ s ]
[ s ]  shadow space
.... call
```

I'm reserving 6 slots (8 byte) so I get 16byte at the call alignment.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Include the disassembly output in your question, not just the raw machine code.

Comment: You messed up stack alignment.

Comment: @Jester can you point me to it? I added some more information how I intended to use the stack.

Comment: The stack should be 16B aligned before a `call`, including before the `call` that got you to `sub rsp, 0x30`.  But remember that `call` pushes an 8B return address.  This is why compiler-generated code uses `sub rsp, 16*n + 8`.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/g/u4UpvV (gcc output for calling an `ms_abi` function, so the registers match what you're expecting.  You could also look at MSVC asm output.)

Comment: Are you sure you need to use a `call [mem]` instead of a `call rel32`?  If you know where `PrintInt` is located in memory while you JIT, and your JIT buffer is in range, you can encode a direct call.  Or you could `mov rax, address` / `call rax` instead of loading the address from a data section.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks a lot @Peter. I changed the alignment algorithm and now everything works!

Comment: Weird that a misaligned stack resulted in an access to `0x0000000000000000`, if that error message is to be believed.  I would have expected a fault when/if some library function used a `movaps` 16-byte aligned-store to a misaligned stack.

Comment: At the moment, I take the address of the function with reinterpret_cast<void*>(&PrintInt).. so I'm getting 64bit address, which I write into a data segment above the object code. Then RIP adressed into it. I'll look into it.